# Roundcube won't connect to IMAPS port 993

Tags: email, dovecot, roundcube

whenever I change dovecot config to use 993 IMAPS port instead of standard 143 IMAP, roundcube refuses to work with errormessage:

> Connection to storage server failed.
>   Server Error: Could not connect to localhost:143: Connection refused

Port 143 is not responding since I disabled it and want to use 993 only.
But I can't get roundcube to use this port even though when I configre standardport for IMAP to 993 in "/etc/roundcube/defaults.inc.php":

```
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://localhost';
// TCP port used for IMAP connections
$config['default_port'] = 993;
```

Dovecot version:

```
ii  dovecot-core                      1:2.2.27-3+deb9u1              amd64        
ii  dovecot-imapd                     1:2.2.27-3+deb9u1              amd64        
ii  dovecot-managesieved              1:2.2.27-3+deb9u1              amd64        
ii  dovecot-sieve                     1:2.2.27-3+deb9u1              amd64
```

Roundcube version:

```
ii  roundcube                         1.2.3+dfsg.1-4   
ii  roundcube-core                    1.2.3+dfsg.1-4   
ii  roundcube-mysql                   1.2.3+dfsg.1-4   
ii  roundcube-plugins                 1.2.3+dfsg.1-4    
ii  roundcube-plugins-extra           1.2.1-20160803
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It was an error within my settings. Because of the certificate u need use the proper hostname and not localhost.

```
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://FQDNofhostname';
// TCP port used for IMAP connections
$config['default_port'] = 993;
```